# Is $p(x)=a\frac{x^2}{x}+b$ a linear polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, continuity

My question at first, may seem too simple,

> Is $p(x)=a\frac{x^2}x+b$ a linear polynomial?

But as we see the polynomial $p(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. So if it is not a polynomial, which function is this? 
 
I got this definition on Wikipedia:

> "Polynomial functions are a class of functions having many important properties. They are all continuous, smooth, entire, computable, etc."

Comment: Just a slight terminological point- what you are calling a 'linear polynomial'  is usually called either a polynomial of degree 1 or a linear function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it is NOT a polynomial. However it has a unique continuous extension to a polynomial ($ax+b$). However AS WRITTEN, it is not a polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by "a unique continuous extension"?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal There is a unique function that is continuous that agrees with $p(x)$ on the domain of $p(x)$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: We often say, in this kind of case, that $p(x)$ has a *removable discontinuity* at $(0, b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $p(x)$ is $\Bbb{R}/\{0\}$ whereas the domain a polynomial (in the sense you have implied in your question) is $\Bbb{R}$ so $p(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: To make it explicit I was assuming that you meant a polynomial as a function of a real or complex variable. A polynomial isn't necessarily a function.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is philosophical haha. Really, the function is not defined in $x=0$. But... We can redefined f in $x=0$ because the limit exist! :).

In complex analysis this is a "singularity"

Comment: The function is equal to a polynomial ax+b but in x=0 has a open point